# In topbar there is doubled dropdown name

Tags: drop-down-menu, zurb-foundation

When I want to use `<li class="has-dropdown">` I got the name of dropdown doubled.
I have tried copy-paste topbar html part directly from foundation's doc, then I tried to copy from different already prepared templates. Everywhere I got the same issue.

[Picture of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oM6zs.png)

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/normalize.css" %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/main.css" %}">

    <script src="{% static "js/vendor/modernizr.js" %}"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="fixed">

         <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar>
          <ul class="title-area">

            <li class="name">
              <h1>
                <a href="#">
                  Top Bar Title
                </a>
              </h1>
            </li>
            <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>menu</span></a></li>
          </ul>

          <section class="top-bar-section">

            <ul class="right">
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li class="has-dropdown">
                <a href="#">Main Item 1</a>
                <ul class="dropdown">
                  <li><label>Section Name</label></li>
                  <li class="has-dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="">Has Dropdown, Level 1</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown">
                      <li><a href="#">Dropdown Options</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Dropdown Options</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Level 2</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Subdropdown Option</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Subdropdown Option</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Subdropdown Option</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Dropdown Option</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Dropdown Option</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li><label>Section Name</label></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Dropdown Option</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Dropdown Option</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Dropdown Option</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">See all →</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Main Item 2</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li class="has-dropdown">
                <a href="#">Main Item 3</a>
                <ul class="dropdown">
                  <li><a href="#">Dropdown Option</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Dropdown Option</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Dropdown Option</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">See all →</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </section>
        </nav>
</div>

<script src="{% static "js/vendor/jquery.js" %}"></script>
<script src="{% static "js/foundation.min.js" %}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).foundation();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly found the solution.

- The 1st (right) way:

in index.html it is necessary to change

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).foundation();
</script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).foundation({topbar: {mobile_show_parent_link : false}});
</script>
```

For my needs I also added `custom_back_text : false` and all together looks like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).foundation({topbar: {custom_back_text : false,
                                    mobile_show_parent_link : false}});
</script>
```

- The 2nd way:

Directly in `foundation.topbar.js` edit `mobile_show_parent_link` from `true` (default) to `false`, e.g. `mobile_show_parent_link : false,`

I have no idea why mobile_show_parent_link works in desktop mode, while from the name I understand as it should work only on mobile devices.